# Where is my mistake in the evaluation of this integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation

Proof that
\begin{align*}
    \int_0^1\frac{x\ln^2{x}}{1-x^4}dx=\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)
\end{align*}
My try
\begin{align*}
    \int_0^1\frac{x\ln^2{x}}{1-x^4}dx&=\int_0^1x\ln^2{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty ({x^4})^{n-1}dx\\
    \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^1x\ln^2{(x)}x^{4n-4}dx&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^1\ln^2{(x)}x^{4n-3}dx
\end{align*}
IBP (Integration By Parts) $u=\ln^2{x}$ and $dv=x^{4n-3}$

\begin{align*}
    \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^1\ln^2{(x)}x^{4n-3}dx&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{\ln^2{(x)}x^{4n-2}}{4n-2}\Big|_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{2\ln{x}}{x}\frac{x^{4n-2}}{4n-2}dx\right]\\
    =\sum_{n=1}^\infty-\frac{2}{4n-2}\left[\int_0^1\ln{(x)}x^{4n-3}dx\right]
\end{align*}
IBP $u=\ln{x}$ and $dv=x^{4n-3}$
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{n=1}^\infty-\frac{2}{4n-2}\left[\int_0^1\ln{(x)}x^{4n-3}dx\right]&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty-\frac{2}{4n-2}\left[\frac{\ln{(x)}x^{4n-2}}{4n-2}\Big|_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{x^{4n-2}}{x(4n-2)}dx\right]\\
    \sum_{n=1}^\infty-\frac{2}{4n-2}\frac{-1}{4n-2}\int_0^1x^{4n-2}dx&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{(4n-2)^2}\frac{x^{4n-2}}{4n-2}\Big|_0^1\\
    \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{(4n-2)^3}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{8(2n-1)^3}=\frac{1}{4}\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)^3}}_S\\
\end{align*}
$S$ is equal to the sum of the odd numbers of the zeta function evaluated at 3
\begin{align*}
    \zeta(3)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3}\\
    \frac{\zeta(3)}{8}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)^3}\\
    S&=\zeta(3)-\frac{\zeta(3)}{8}\\
    S&=\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}\\
    \therefore\\
    \frac{1}{4}S&=\frac{7\zeta(3)}{32}
\end{align*}
Clearly there is an error in at least one of the answer, Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Being lost in your calculations, I did not find the (possible) mistakes and I give you another way to solve the problem
$$\frac x {1-x^4}=\frac x {(1-x^2)(1+x^2)}=\frac{x}{2 \left(x^2+1\right)}-\frac{1}{4 (x-1)}-\frac{1}{4 (x+1)}$$
$$\frac{x}{2 \left(x^2+1\right)}=\frac{x}{2 \left(x+i)(x-i)\right)}=\frac{1}{4 (x+i)}+\frac{1}{4 (x-i)}$$

$$\int_0^1 \frac {\log^2(x)}{x+i} dx=\frac{3 \zeta (3)}{16}-\frac{i \pi ^3}{16}$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac {\log^2(x)}{x-i} dx=\frac{3 \zeta (3)}{16}+\frac{i \pi ^3}{16}$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac {\log^2(x)}{x-1} dx=\frac32\zeta (3)$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac {\log^2(x)}{x+1} dx=-2 \zeta (3)$$

As a total

$$    \int_0^1\frac{x\log^2(x)}{1-x^4}dx=\frac{7}{32}\zeta(3)$$

This has been checked numerically.

Another way to do it is to consider that
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log ^2(x)}{x+a}dx=-2 \text{Li}_3\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)$$ which would lead to the same result.

**Edit**

Let us do it using another way
$$    \int_0^1\frac{x\log^2(x)}{1-x^4}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 x^{4n+1}\log^2(x)\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4 (2 n+1)^3}=\frac{7}{32}\zeta(3)$$

Comment: Sorry for the mess, but would you consider the book answer is mistaken?

Comment: @SamuelA.Morales. For sure ! Just use numerical integration for a check.

Comment: Thank you! And again, sorry for the mess

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^2{x}}{1-x^4}dx&\overset{y=x^2}=\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2{y}}{1-y^2}dy\\
&=\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2{y}}{1-y}dy-\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^2{x}}{1-x^2}dx\\
&\overset{y=x^2}=\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2{y}}{1-y}dy-\frac{1}{64}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2{y}}{1-y}dy\\
&=\frac{7}{64}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2{y}}{1-y}dy\\
&=\frac{7}{64}\times 2\zeta(3)\\
&=\frac{7}{32}\zeta(3)\\
\end{align}

NB:
I assume that $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\ln^2{y}}{1-y}dy=2\zeta(3)$ (Taylor series expansion)